# HTML5 Document loads first layer first, then lower layers second, and so on

Tags: javascript, css, html

Disclaimer: I'm new to Stack Overflow and HTML5/CSS/JavaScript. Also, my scenario is simplified.

I'm interacting with a GUI someone else has developed. The GUI involves an HTML5/CSS/JavaScript page. There are 2 screens: one simple screen that acts as a splash screen, and another that has a lockscreen button on it. The splash screen displays on top of the button screen. Pressing on the splash screen hides said screen from view, displaying the button screen. Pressing the lockscreen button re-displays the splash screen. The lockscreen button is a circle with a lock icon in it.

The issue is that sometimes the lock icon doesn't appear in the lockscreen button. The button icon reappears when the button is pressed, or after exactly 2 minutes of no user interaction.

Initially, there was no splash screen--the page would just first display with the lockscreen button. I thought that the missing button icon was due to the client-side not having enough time to render/parse/load(?) all the page, so the developer displayed the splash screen atop the other first.

In retrospect, I think that if the icon wasn't loaded yet, then slapping another screen on top of it wouldn't force the icon to refresh/reappear. I wouldn't think that interacting with the splash screen would have an effect on the lockscreen button, right?

Furthermore, I'm testing by displaying the GUI on the Google Chrome browser. When I'm using Developer Tools and slowing down the network (to "Fast 3g"), I notice that the HTML5 Document is loading the "top layers" of the DOM first before entering the "sub-layers". For instance, this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head></head>
<body></body>
```

loads before this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <!-- MORE STUFF -->
</head>
<body>
    <div></div>
    <!-- MORE STUFF, including but not limited to JavaScript linking -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="some/javascript.js"></script>
</body>
```

which loads before this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <!-- MORE STUFF -->
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div class="lock-icon"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- MORE STUFF, including but not limited to JavaScript linking-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="some/javascript.js"></script>
</body>
```

If this is the case, then perhaps the document doesn't have enough time to load the icon before all the JavaScript functions are read/run? Perhaps that explains the exactness of the return of the icon after 2 minutes of no user interaction?

Comment: A div can't be in the head!

Comment: And it looks like you need control over the page load. You want your scripts to start once the page is loaded: `document.body.addEventListener("load", function(){})` is one way to wait for all the content to be present.

Comment: Hard to help you without seeing the code. I'm not sure exactly what you're asking but it sounds like you need to structure your includes and links more efficiently. I'd suggest using jQuery's `$(document).ready()` functionality to stop JS from running until the page is fully loaded

Comment: @Tom, I think you're on the right track. The code involves linking JavaScript files. I've added that detail in the question.

Comment: @musikreck Right so without seeing the contents of said `javascript.js` files, I'd say use either of the above suggestions (mine if you have linked in jQuery, @Mouser 's if you have not). A quick google search will tell you how to properly implement them, but they go on line 1 and basically stop the declared function from being run until the document has fully loaded.